# Creating an Complex Layout in C# [Xamarin Forms]

Tags: c#, xml, user-interface, xamarin.forms

In my app, I need a page that will hold the user's profile, but I've been struggling to create complex UI in xamarin forms.

I saw this on the xamarin docs, but I'm not sure how to use XAML and they don't have any examples on how to get the same look in c#. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Documentation page: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout/

XAML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="TheBusinessTumble.StackLayoutPage"
BackgroundColor="Maroon"
Title="StackLayouts">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Maroon">
                <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="100" VerticalOptions="Start" Color="Gray" />
                <Button BorderRadius="30" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />
                <StackLayout HeightRequest="100" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="20" BackgroundColor="Maroon">
                    <Label Text="User Name" FontSize="28" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Entry Text="Bio + Hashtags" TextColor="White"
                        BackgroundColor="Maroon" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="5">
                    <StackLayout Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="White" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Label FontSize="14" TextColor="Black" Text="Accent Color" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="White" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Maroon" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Label FontSize="14" TextColor="Black" Text="Primary Color" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label FontSize="14" Text="Age:" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="100" />
                    <Entry HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="35" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Maroon" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label FontSize="14" Text="Interests:" TextColor="White"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="100" />
                    <Entry HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Xamarin.Forms" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Maroon" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label FontSize="14" Text="Ask me about:" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="100"/>
                    <Entry HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Xamarin, C#, .NET, Mono..." TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Maroon" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

What I currently have:

```
public class ProfilePageCS : ContentPage
{
    public ProfilePageCS()
    {
        var layout = new StackLayout();

        var boxOne = new BoxView
        {
            Color = Color.Blue,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HeightRequest = 450
        };

        var boxTwo = new BoxView
        {
            Color = Color.Green,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HeightRequest = 175
        };

        layout.Children.Add(boxTwo);
        layout.Children.Add(boxOne);
        layout.Spacing = 0;
        Content = layout;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is specifically called XAML.

Comment: Shoot! Okay, thanks for the correction

Comment: so your question is essentially, "Please translate this huge piece of XAML into C# for me"?  That's not really appropriate for SO.  It would probably be more appropriate to show us a mockup of the UI you're trying to build and asking a *specific* question about the parts you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not how I meant it to come off. I'm having a hard time understanding how I can achieve the same thing with c#.

What I'm basically trying to do is split the screen into a top section that's 30% and the rest would be the bottom half. within the top half I want to center a picture with a label below it. I've been on this for the past 8 hours, but haven't been able to advance at all :(

Comment: See, that is a much better question than what you actually asked.  I personally would start with a Grid, where the first row was 30% and the second row was 70%.

Comment: Okay, so I need to work on my questions then as well lol. So I managed to separate it with stackedlayout, I'm not sure how to add elements to one another. I added more code to show you what I have so far

Comment: you can nest StackLayouts inside one another - just create a new stacklayout, add it's children, and then add it as a child of one your parent stacklayouts

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting out with Xamarin Forms, it is really worth the effort to learn XAML and use it to describe pages rather than use code.

The approach you are taking will lead to code that is difficult to read and maintain. You will end up with both UI and business logic in the same file. You won't be able to use the MVVM pattern and unit testing becomes more difficult.

[Here is the first page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/getting_started_with_xaml/) in a series that helps you lean XAML. There are plenty of other resources on the internet.

Here is XAML for the layout you describes above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Example.Pages.MainPage">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
            <Image Source="image.png"/>
            <Label Text="Image Caption"/>
        </StackLayout>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use XAML compilation. 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/

You just apply an attribute to the class, and you will have the same benefits of using C# (i.e. performance), but you will be able to easily define your elements in a declarative away (i.e. as with XAML).